# Drop downs don't work in HTTPS but work fine in HTTP

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dropdownbox

On a clients website my dropdowns that I have set up for the 3 products are not working when I view the page via HTTPS.

Here it is working on HTTP: http://bit.ly/WeY3NP

Here it is not working on HTTPS: http://bit.ly/X0iHTo

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?  Q: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: And what dropdowns don't work? I can't see any difference in functionality between the sites...

Comment: @paulsm4

On both links scroll down and click on a product, either mens dress, mens ankle, or womens ankle. In HTTP there will be an extra step that will drop down for you.

Here's the code:

Comment: I don't see any drop downs.  Are you sure you're not just trying to sell us socks?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#showwomens").click(function(){
$(".womenswhiteankletabels").slideDown(0);
});
</script>

Comment: Yes I'm sure :P when you click on "select" an extra option should drop down for you to select how often you want the socks to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is not being included properly on https.

You can see that $ is undefined in the chrome developers console when using https://. I can't test right now but i suspect that if you include JQuery differently it will work.

Change :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```